# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have implemented a little test application in React to fetch data via AJAX, but it is not working as inteded, hence i get following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefinedInline JSX script
```

Code is as following:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script type="text/jsx">   
var Bodypart = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.name}
            </div>
        )
    }
})    

var BodypartList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {data: []};
    },
    componentWillMount: function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: this.props.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          this.setState({bodyparts: data});
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
          console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
      });
    },
    render: function() {
        var bodypartItems = this.state.bodyparts.map(function (bodypart) {
            return (
                <Bodypart 
                    name={bodypart.name} 
                />
            );
        });
        return (
        <div>
            {bodypartItems}
        </div>
        );
    }
});    

React.render(
    <BodypartList url="/api/bodyparts/" />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
</script>
```

The response from `/api/bodyparts/`:

```
{
    "bodyparts": [
        {
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "Face"
        }, 
        {
            "id": 3, 
            "name": "Mouth"
        }, 
        {
            "id": 2, 
            "name": "Nose"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At initial render `this.state.bodyparts`is `undefined` hence the error you got.

you should return

```
{bodyparts:[]}
```

from `getInitialState`.

Also in your `success` callback you should set state like:

```
this.setState(data);
```

because your api already returns `bodyparts` as part of its result.

Comment: Lack of coffee creates significant mistakes.

Comment: Which is better? creating an initial state on getInitialState ```{bodyparts:[]}```

 or making an explicit conditional check when the this.state.bodyparts is set? like this.

```var bodypartItems = this.state.bodyparts && this.state.bodyparts.map(function (bodypart) {
            return (
                <Bodypart 
                    name={bodypart.name} 
                />
            );
        });```

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.bodyparts` is undefined. the component is rendering before the ajax has completed. Try setting an initial state